# Where to instantiate classes dependent on main class?

Tags: c++, oop, instance, instantiation, sfml

I'm currently working on a 2D game engine with SFML, and started off procedurally but decided It will be better in the long run by moving it to OOP. I understand the concept of OOP, however, I'm not exactly sure where I should define my instantiations to the other classes (ImageManager, Grid, etc.)

For example, My `Engine` class depends on `ImageManager`, and many functions in `Engine` rely on variables from `ImageManager`. Thus, I can't simply declare and define the instance of the `ImageManager` class within a single function, since It won't be available in the other functions.

What I've done is this:
Engine.h:

```
class Engine
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    grid (*gridArray)[SIZE];
    ...//more variables, removing for length
    //Initializes the engine
    bool Init(); //Main Game Loop
    void MainLoop(); //Renders one frame
    void RenderFrame(); //Processes user input
    void ProcessInput(); //Updates all Engine internals
public:
    Engine(int w, int h, int tileSize);
    ~Engine();
    ImageManager * imageManager;
    GridClass * gridClass;
    ...//removed some methods for length
};
```

So basically, you can see I'm declaring two classes in the header, `ImageManager` and `GridClass`. 
Inside Engine.cpp:

```
Engine::Engine(int w, int h, int tileSize)
{
    imageManager = new ImageManager;
    gridClass = new GridClass();
    gridArray = new grid[SIZE][SIZE]();
    masterArray = new unsigned char[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
    videoSize = sf::Vector2i(w, h);
    this->tileSize = tileSize;
    startX = startY = endX = endY = 0;
}
```

I'm defining the classes. I do it in the constructor because I'm not sure where I'm supposed to do it, to conform with good practices. 
I've been having problems with the elements of `imageManager` becoming corrupted, so I'm wondering if the way I'm doing it is a bad idea or not.

If it's a bad idea, could you please tell me where I should instantiate these classes? Remember that many functions within Engine rely on variables from these instances of these classes, and I don't really want to pass a LOT of parameters to each function.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should make the imageManager and gridClass private, to narrow down what can change them. You might want to consider putting them in a smart pointer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating member objects from inside your class make your code less modular/flexible.

Imagine you have various implementations of your `ImageManager` class (e.g. you may want to have a `MockImageManager` when unit testing your `Engine`, or you may want to try out your `Engine` with various third party `ImageManager`), the only way you can make your `Engine` use one implementation of `ImageManager` or the other is by modifying the implementation of `Engine` itself.

This prevents you to take advantage of the dynamic dispatch of OOP, and C++ in particular (keywords here being: inheritance, interfaces and virtual calls).

You will find that your code will become much more flexible with something like:

```
class Engine
{
public:
    Engine(int w, int h, int tileSize, const std::shared_ptr<ImageManger>& im, const std::shared_ptr<GridClass>& gc);
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<ImageManger> imageManager;
    std::shared_ptr<GridClass> gridClass;
    // ....
};
```

And just copy the shared_ptr that you are given in the constructor:

```
Engine::Engine(int w, int h, int tileSize, const std::shared_ptr<ImageManger>& im, const std::shared_ptr<GridClass>& gc) : imageManager(im), gridClass(gc)
{
    // ...
}
```

The way to instantiate the lot:

```
int main(void)
{
    Engine engine(42, 42, 42, std::make_shared<ImageManager>(), std::make_shared<GridClass>());
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

This way, all you have to change to provide a new implementation of `ImageManager` (provided that `ImageManager`'s interface is made up of virtual calls) is to code it up as `MyRevolutionaryImageManager` (which would derive from `ImageManager`), and change the `std::make_shared` call in main to `std::make_shared<MyRevolitionaryImageManager>()`. You don't even have to recompile `Engine`, the new implementation will be used (the beauty of virtual that allows old code to call new code)!

Now of course if `ImageManager` and/or `GridClass` are only implementation details of `Engine`, and if there is no need for flexibility, then it's fair enough to instantiate them from within `Engine`.

The use of `shared_ptr` is not needed you can use normal pointers if you want, but then you need to think about when/where to delete things.

Comment: Accepted answer as it's the most detailed

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, good job making the switch.  OOP is a very good choice for game production.

The short answer is that its ok to have classes inside of other classes like this. And there's nothing wrong with instantiating these in the constructor. The point of the constructor is to initialize everything that an object of that class will need to start working, so if you think that your `Engine` needs an `imageManager` to function properly, instantiating it in the constructor is fine.

However, keep in mind that placing an object inside another object is ok so long as you arent going to need to call `imageManager` outside of your `Engine` functions often.  Then you would have to use a syntax like this:

```
engine.imageManager.somefunction()
```

This can get extremely messy and convoluted if you need to access something that is nested deep down, but as long as you don't nest too many objects like this, you should be fine. If you think that you are going to need to use `imageManager` a lot outside of the engine, it might be best to instantiate `imageManager` separately and have private variables in `Engine` that can hold the values that you need.  Then, you can create some public functions in `Engine` that could receive any updated info from `imageManager` and update the variables  accordingly.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite acceptable to do it the way you have done it. Upon entering the `Engine::Engine()` body, memory for `Engine` will have been allocated. No potential for corrupting `imageManager` with that.

When allocating all the members inside the constructor, though, it becomes very similar to making them *part of* `Engine` (termed ["Composition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)), i.e.

```
ImageManager imageManager;
GridClass gridClass;
```

This way, you do not have to worry about cleaning up memory. 
On the other hand, you lose flexibility. The way you have implemented it, `Engine` *has an* `ImageManager` (["Aggregation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation)), which can conveniently be replaced while the program is running.